# Need help please with a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, left-join

I need help with the following query in mysql.
I have two tables with the following structure.

```
 Assigned       
id  | user_id | ticket_id
1      12        6525
2      9         6520
3      6         6525
4      6         6540
```

```
Answers         
id_rta  | answer         | id_ticket | id_per
10      response text       6525        12
11      response text       6525        6
12      response text       6520        9
13      response text       6525        12
```

Assigned Table

id: AI PK

user_id: User ID that was assigned to the case

ticket_id: Case Id assigned to it

---

Table Answers

id_rta: AI PK

answer: the response text

id_ticket: Id Case which gave response

id_per: User ID that said the case

---

I need to check if the user who is assigned the case and responded (YES - NO)

I tried with LEFT JOIN to bring information and using the option

IF (r.id_per = e.user_id, 'YES', 'NO')
AS Resp_Asig

But tell me that all cases have been answered, YES. Of course it is not.

Honestly and I am somewhat desperate, I spend hours and hours with attempts and reading articles and tutorials on the internet but I could not really solve anything.
Please help me :(

Comment: Assigned table, id: AI PK - repeated values `3` ?

Comment: Show the query you tried.

Comment: @BhupeshC Sorry I'm wrong on the value, is 4

Comment: Based on the data, in the question, could you also put in what output you would expect from the query. As it is I'm confused as well...

Comment: @user1032531 I try
SELECT 
IF(r.id_per=e.user_id,'YES','NO') 
             AS Resp_Asig
FROM 
Assigned e
LEFT JOIN (
Answers r
) ON e.user_id = r.id_per

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Hi, Thanks.

I need the query to tell me if the person to whom you assign a case already answered YES or NO.
Eg
John Doe in the system has the ID 9, and John Doe was assigned the case 6252.
To find out if you answered reviewed the response table if the user 9 said the 6252 case.

I regret not understand me very well, but I'm Hispanic and my English is basic.

Comment: What response table? Answers.responsetext = "YES" or "NO", contains them???. Whether they have responded is easy. The content of the response more difficult, especially seeing as given your structure they could have multiple YESes and NOs...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thank you very much for your help, and I could solve my problem, thank you infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: -

```
Select asgn.user_id, asgn.ticket_id, answ.answer
from
Assigned asgn
inner join
Answers answ
on asgn.user_id = answ.id_per
and asgn.ticket_id = answ.id_ticket
and upper(answer) like '%YES%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d0e/4)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer,

But unfortunately for me is not what I'm looking for.

I need the query to tell me if the person to Whom you assign a case Already answered the case YES or NO. But do not look for the word YES or NO.

Eg John Doe in the system has the ID 9, and John Doe Assigned the case was 6252. To find out if you answered reviewed the response if the user table in September said the 6252 case. I regret not understand me very well, but I'm Hispanic and my english is basic

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and I could solve my problem, based in a reply could find my solution, I think I love you lol thank you! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d0e/8